# как скопировать exe файл чтобы на нем осталось "Run this program as an administrator"

Tags: windows, windows-10, exe, copy

Есть exe файл на котором в совместимости стоит Run this program as an administrator:
[image: 1]

Но если скопировать файл через:

```
shutil.copy2()
```

Тогда Run this program as an administrator пропадет:

[image: 2]

Как скопировать чтобы все осталось?

Comment: Эти опции хранятся в реестре в ключах `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers` и `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers`. И привязаны к имени файла с полным путём.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Эти опции хранятся в реестре в ключах HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers и HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers. И привязаны к имени файла с полным путём.

Спасибо @GrAnd

Answer (score 1):

Этот параметр сохранить не получиться. Судя по тегам к вашему вопросу вы скомпилировали свою python-программу. Если вы пользуетесь утилитой Pyinstaller для этого, то в Pyinstaller есть параметр `--uac-admin`. Благодаря нему ваша программа будет запускаться от имени администратора автоматически.